# Apache camel kafka component fail to serialize header after update from 2.21.1 to 2.21.2

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-producer-api

After I update the apache camel from version 2.21.1 to 2.21.2 I am getting the follow error:

**due Magic v1 does not support record headers**

I see at https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/docs/kafka-component.adoc that in version 2.22 all headers are serialized to the topic, I don't know why.
I set up severals headers on the router, And I dont know it serialize to topic and as mainly as byte.

What I need to do? Apply headerFilterStrategy?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks

> What I need to do? Apply headerFilterStrategy?

No. It is not filter issue.

The issue is the version mismatch between Kafka and client you are using. Please check the version of Kafka broker and then see which version of consumer is camel Kafka component using. Make sure they are compatible.

Comment: But in the documentation say that from the version 2.22 , the Camel put all headers in the Kafka Header and I have one object in header as JSON and the Kafka only support bytes, That's why I thought it was Camel filter strategy, the documentation say that we can filter the header for not send to Kafka.

Comment: @RenatoGarcia can you provide the exact stacktrace of error?